# pynng: how to setup, and keep using, multiple Contexts on a REP0 socket

Tags: python-asyncio, nanomsg, pynng

I'm working on a "server" thread, which takes care of some IO calls for a bunch of "clients".

The communication is done using [pynng v0.5.0](https://github.com/codypiersall/pynng), the server has its own [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) loop.

Each client "registers" by sending a first request, and then loops receiving the results and sending back READY messages.

On the server, the goal is to treat the first message of each client as a registration request, and to create a dedicated worker task which will loop doing IO stuff, sending the result and waiting for the READY message of that particular client.

To implement this, I'm trying to leverage the [Context](https://pynng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#context) feature of REP0 sockets.

**Side notes**

- <s>*I would have liked to tag this question with [nng](/questions/tagged/nng) and [pynng](/questions/tagged/pynng), but I don't have enough reputation.*</s>
- *Although I'm an avid consumer of this site, it's my first question :)*
- *I do know about the PUB/SUB pattern, let's just say that for self-instructional purposes, I chose not to use it for this service.*

**Problem:**

After a few iterations, some READY messages are intercepted by the registration coroutine of the server, instead of being routed to the proper worker task.

Since I can't share the code, I wrote a reproducer for my issue and included it below.

Worse, as you can see in the output, some result messages are sent to the wrong client (`ERROR:root:<Worker 1>: worker/client mismatch, exiting.`).

It looks like a bug, but I'm not entirely sure I understand how to use the contexts correctly, so any help would be appreciated.

**Environment:**

- winpython-3.8.2
- [pynng v0.5.0+dev (46fbbcb2)](https://github.com/codypiersall/pynng/commit/46fbbcb2b775e18681113b1bfd516c85f61ef350), with [nng v1.3.0 (ff99ee51)](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng/commit/ff99ee51b34268f00aab3efd858e0798e92417c3)

**Code:**

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import pynng
import threading

NNG_DURATION_INFINITE = -1
ENDPOINT = 'inproc://example_endpoint'


class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()
        self._client_tasks = dict()

    @staticmethod
    async def _worker(ctx, client_id):
        while True:
            # Remember, the first 'receive' has already been done by self._new_client_handler()

            logging.debug(f"<Worker {client_id}>: doing some IO")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            logging.debug(f"<Worker {client_id}>: sending the result")
            # I already tried sending synchronously here instead, just in case the issue was related to that
            # (but it's not)
            await ctx.asend(f"result data for client {client_id}".encode())

            logging.debug(f"<Worker {client_id}>: waiting for client READY msg")
            data = await ctx.arecv()
            logging.debug(f"<Worker {client_id}>: received '{data}'")
            if data != bytes([client_id]):
                logging.error(f"<Worker {client_id}>: worker/client mismatch, exiting.")
                return

    async def _new_client_handler(self):
        with pynng.Rep0(listen=ENDPOINT) as socket:
            max_workers = 3 + 1  # Try setting it to 3 instead, to stop creating new contexts => now it works fine
            while await asyncio.sleep(0, result=True) and len(self._client_tasks) < max_workers:
                # The issue is here: at some point, the existing client READY messages get
                # intercepted here, instead of being routed to the proper worker context.
                # The intent here was to open a new context only for each *new* client, I was
                # assuming that a 'recv' on older worker contexts would take precedence.
                ctx = socket.new_context()
                data = await ctx.arecv()
                client_id = data[0]

                if client_id in self._client_tasks:
                    logging.error(f"<Server>: We already have a task for client {client_id}")
                    continue  # just let the client block on its 'recv' for now

                logging.debug(f"<Server>: New client : {client_id}")
                self._client_tasks[client_id] = asyncio.create_task(self._worker(ctx, client_id))

            await asyncio.gather(*list(self._client_tasks.values()))

    def run(self) -> None:
        # The "server" thread has its own asyncio loop
        asyncio.run(self._new_client_handler(), debug=True)


class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client_id: int):
        super(Client, self).__init__()
        self._id = client_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Client {self._id}>'

    def run(self):
        with pynng.Req0(dial=ENDPOINT, resend_time=NNG_DURATION_INFINITE) as socket:
            while True:
                logging.debug(f"{self}: READY")
                socket.send(bytes([self._id]))
                data_str = socket.recv().decode()
                logging.debug(f"{self}: received '{data_str}'")
                if data_str != f"result data for client {self._id}":
                    logging.error(f"{self}: client/worker mismatch, exiting.")
                    return


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    threads = [Server(),
               *[Client(i) for i in range(3)]]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
DEBUG:root:<Client 1>: READY
DEBUG:root:<Client 0>: READY
DEBUG:root:<Client 2>: READY
DEBUG:root:<Server>: New client : 1
DEBUG:root:<Worker 1>: doing some IO
DEBUG:root:<Server>: New client : 0
DEBUG:root:<Worker 0>: doing some IO
DEBUG:root:<Server>: New client : 2
DEBUG:root:<Worker 2>: doing some IO
DEBUG:root:<Worker 1>: sending the result
DEBUG:root:<Client 1>: received 'result data for client 1'
DEBUG:root:<Client 1>: READY
ERROR:root:<Server>: We already have a task for client 1
DEBUG:root:<Worker 1>: waiting for client READY msg
DEBUG:root:<Worker 0>: sending the result
DEBUG:root:<Client 0>: received 'result data for client 0'
DEBUG:root:<Client 0>: READY
DEBUG:root:<Worker 0>: waiting for client READY msg
DEBUG:root:<Worker 1>: received 'b'\x00''
ERROR:root:<Worker 1>: worker/client mismatch, exiting.
DEBUG:root:<Worker 2>: sending the result
DEBUG:root:<Client 2>: received 'result data for client 2'
DEBUG:root:<Client 2>: READY
DEBUG:root:<Worker 2>: waiting for client READY msg
ERROR:root:<Server>: We already have a task for client 2
```

**Edit (2020-04-10):** updated both pynng and the underlying nng.lib to their latest version (master branches), still the same issue.

Comment: thanks for the pynng tag ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the sources of both nng and pynng, and confirming my understanding with the maintainers, I can now answer my own question.

When using a context on a REP0 socket, there are a few things to be aware of.

As advertised, *send/asend()* is guaranteed to be routed to the same peer you last received from.

The data from the next *recv/arecv()* on this same context, however, is NOT guaranteed to be coming from the same peer.

Actually, the underlying nng call to `rep0_ctx_recv()` merely reads the next socket pipe with available data, so there's no guarantee that said data is coming from the same peer than the last recv/send pair.

In the reproducer above, I was concurrently calling *arecv()* both on a new context (in the `Server._new_client_handler()` coroutine), and on each worker context (in the `Server._worker()` coroutine).

So what I had previously described as the next request being "intercepted" by the main coroutine was merely a race condition.

One solution would be to only receive from the `Server._new_client_handler()` coroutine, and have the workers only handle one request. Note that in this case, the workers are no longer dedicated to a particular peer. If this behavior is needed, the routing of incoming requests must be handled at application level.

```py
class Server(threading.Thread):
    @staticmethod
    async def _worker(ctx, data: bytes):
        client_id = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='big', signed=False)
        logging.debug(f"<Worker {client_id}>: doing some IO")
        await asyncio.sleep(1 + 10 * random.random())

        logging.debug(f"<Worker {client_id}>: sending the result")
        await ctx.asend(f"result data for client {client_id}".encode())

    async def _new_client_handler(self):
        with pynng.Rep0(listen=ENDPOINT) as socket:
            while await asyncio.sleep(0, result=True):
                ctx = socket.new_context()
                data = await ctx.arecv()
                asyncio.create_task(self._worker(ctx, data))

    def run(self) -> None:
        # The "server" thread has its own asyncio loop
        asyncio.run(self._new_client_handler(), debug=False)
```